# Slow trackpad: finetuning and sensitivity/speed/accelation configuration

Tags: release-loki, settings, touchpad, mouse

I have **set the speed of my trackpad to max** in the system settings.
However, the trackpad is **still quite slow**.

In essence, I have to move my finger around quite a lot to get from one end of the screen to the other (*sensitivity or speed*?). Also, the moment I take my finger off the trackpad the cursor stops moving right away, instead of slowly losing speed and then stopping (*coasting*?).

What is the "standard" way to adjust and finetune a trackpad on Elementary OS Loki, *beyond the basic settings in the system settings app*?

I would like my lenovo trackpad to behave **similarly to mac trackpads on OS X** (not the same functionality which requires more software I assume, but similar sensitivity, speed, coasting etc).

Comment: That's a shame. I don't know a standard way, but Linux generally doesn't have scroll acceleration, unlike OS X and iPads and Android. You can do it in web browsers individually though http://askubuntu.com/questions/27270/increasing-scroll-speed

Comment: I had a similar issue. though on my system the mouse settings had no effect, whether I turned it all the way down or all the way up. I found at this issue was caused by a kernel update that I forced going from 4.4 to 4.8. Did you do a kernel update to anything other than what is pushed via updates?